# SUM of one column + another column

Tags: sql-server

I want to get the sum of one column and return the value in another column with the same query. The second column stays the same at all times. My columns look something like this:

```
A    | B 
4.19 | 111222 
3.29 | 111222
5.10 | 111222
1.11 | 111222
```

I want the sum of column A, and to simply return column B.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(A) FROM yourTable), B FROM yourTable
```

Subquery could be moved to CTE.

Or

```
SELECT S, B 
FROM YourTable, (SELECT SUM(A) S FROM yourTable) i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(A) over () sumofA, B
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

For better performance use:

```
DECLARE @A AS FLOAT
SELECT @A = SUM(A) FROM YourTable

SELECT @A, B FROM YourTable
```

The sub query will runs once in every row of YourTable. But above query runs only once.